# Filtering and modifiying a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Good Day,

I have a task such that given a list [3,9,11,2,14], I want to filter out any value greater than 6.  I have that working right now.

```
sift([],[]).
sift([X|T], [X|Result]):-
    X > 6,                         /* is X greater than 6 */
    write(isList(Result)),
    /* append([X]|['CCC'], [Result]), but this didn't work */
    sift(T,Result).                /* if so then go find the rest */
sift([ThrowAway|Tail],Result):-    /* disregard the head */
    sift(Tail,Result).             /* and look in the tail */
```

As I mentioned earlier, this returns the correct result.  My dilemma is that if there *is* a value greater than 6, I want to add the additional value of 'CCC' after number that matches the criteria.  So it would look like:

[9, CCC, 11, CCC, 14, CCC].

I've tried to write out the contents of the list, but when I do that I get the values:

```
12 ?- sift([3,9,11,2,14], Results).
isList(_G2271)isList(_G2276)isList(_G2281)
Results = [9, 11, 14].
13 ?-
```

I'm trying to inspect the contents of the list to see what it is.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this?

TIA,

coson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue when adding the `append([X]|['CCC'], [Result])` is that you instantiate `Result=[X,'CCC']`. You are not just adding `'CCC'` to `Result` but you append `[X]` with `['CCC']` and the result is the list Result (so `Result=[X,'CCC']`). After that when you call `sift(T,Result)`. Result is fully instantiated so adding an element will return false.

There is also another problem, querying  `?- sift([3,9,11,2,14], Results).`gives:

```
?- sift([3,9,11,2,14], Results).
isList(_G1296)isList(_G1301)isList(_G1306)
Results = [9, 11, 14] ;
Results = [9, 11] ;
isList(_G1301)
Results = [9, 14] ;
Results = [9] ;
isList(_G1296)isList(_G1301)
Results = [11, 14] ;
Results = [11] ;
isList(_G1296)
Results = [14] ;
Results = [].
```

It gives so many lists due to the fact that your third clause matches with all input cases. To fix that you could add `X=<6` in the third clause.

Finally you could write:

```
sift([],[]). 
sift([X|T],[X,'CCC'|Result]):-X > 6,sift(T,Result).
sift([ThrowAway|Tail],Result):-ThrowAway=<6,sift(Tail,Result).
```

which fixes both problems. In your example:

```
?- sift([3,9,11,2,14], Results).
Results = [9, 'CCC', 11, 'CCC', 14, 'CCC'] ;
false.
```